# How to use if/else in single line (python -c)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have just started learning python and I am trying to use if/else statement in python -c, but  I keep getting Invalid Syntax error. The reason I want to call if/else with python -c is because I want to call some python modules with if/else in my bash script. Is it possible and I would like to stick to python -c and not python -m?

Below is what I have tried so far

#### Try 1

```
python -c "if False: print 'not working';else print 'working'"
  File "<string>", line 1
    if False: print 'not working';else print 'working'
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

#### Try 2

```
python -c "if False:    print 'not working';else:    print 'working'"
  File "<string>", line 1
    if False:    print 'not working';else:    print 'working'
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

#### Try3

```
python -c "if False:;    print 'not working';else:;    print 'working'"
  File "<string>", line 1
    if False:;    print 'not working';else:;    print 'working'
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this issue?

And what if I want to use if|elif|elif|else kind of statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remember, you can use newlines in shell strings too!

Answer (score 7):

For a true general-purpose solution -- `python -c` is not limited to single lines.

```
python -c '
if True:
  print "hello"
else:
  print "world"
'
```

Of course, you can format your multi-line string as a single line, if you really want to:

```
python -c $'if True:\n\tprint "hello"'\nelse:\n\tprint "world"'
```

...but, also quite obviously, this is a Really Bad Idea.

If you really, really want to wrap Python code in shell, why not use functions? Even better than that, why not use quoted heredocs for your code? (Doing this lets you keep the code itself literal, passing arguments through argv).

```
python_argv_repr() {
  python - "$@" <<'EOF'
import sys
print sys.argv[1:]
EOF
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Make it simple, use the ternary form:

```
$ python -c "print 'A' if False else 'B'"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a conditional expression and print function:

```
C:\> python -c "from __future__ import print_function; print('not wo
rking') if False else print ('working')"
working
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.What if I want to do if|elif|elif|else kind of statement in python -c and not just if|else?

Comment: @mbz_slk Yo cannot write if-else on a single line as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do. Basically something like this  , python -c "sd = 10; if sd == 10: print '10'; elif sd = 15: print '15'; else: print 'unknown'"

Comment: you can nest ternaries.

Comment: @ErikAllik As Erik already mentioned you nest ternary expressions and with print function you can use ternary expressions inside of it as well.

Comment: Thanks. Lemme try that.

Comment: @mbz_slk Did'nt see your updated comment, for that this should suffice: `python -c "sd=10; print '10' if sd==10 else '15' if sd==15 else 'unknown'"`

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
python -c "print 'val1' if False else 'val2'"
```

For several conditions try it:

```
expression1 if condition1 else expression2 if condition2 else expression3
```

for example set a value to a variable:

```
myvar = "val1" if a>10 else "val2" if a==10 else "val3"
```